# Spring MVC, JSP do nor load properly my css

Tags: java, css, jsp, spring-mvc

I created simple web-app using spring mvc with form in jsp and some css in it. I run it on tomcat7

Thats my code:

```
public class SpittrWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{RootConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.springinaction.spittr.web")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer){
        configurer.enable();
    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/spitter")
public class SpitterController {

    @Autowired
    public SpitterController(SpitterRepository spitterRepository){
        this.spitterRepository = spitterRepository;
    }

    public SpitterController() {}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showRegistrationForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(new Spitter());
        return "registrationForm";
    }
}
```

Finally jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

    <%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Spittr</title>
      <style>
        div.errors {
          backgraund-color: #ffcccc;
          border: 2px solid red;
        }
        label.error {
          color: #ffcccc;
        }
        input.error{
          backgraund-color: #ffcccc;
        }

      </style>
    </head>
    <br>
      <h1>Rejestracja</h1>
      <sf:form method="POST" commandName="spitter">
        <sf:errors path="*" cssClass="errors" element="div"/>

        <sf:label path="firstName" cssErrorClass="error">Imię:</sf:label>
        <sf:input path="firstName"/><br/>

        <sf:label path="lastName" cssErrorClass="error">Nazwisko:</sf:label>
        <sf:input path="lastName"/><br/>

        <sf:label path="username" cssErrorClass="error">Nazwa użytkownika: </sf:label>
        <sf:input path="username"/><br/>

        <sf:label path="email" cssErrorClass="error">Email:</sf:label>
        <sf:input path="email" type="email"/><br/>

        <sf:label path="password" cssErrorClass="error">Password:</sf:label>
        <sf:password element="span" path="password"/><br/>

        <input type="submit" value="Zarejestruj"/>
      </sf:form>
      <hr />
    </body>
    </html>
```

My problem is that, when i'am opening website under my browser(doesn't matter which one) just part of css's is loaded. It uses only **border: 2px solid red;** and  **color: #ffcccc;**. I can't find solution for that problem. Could it be some issue with encoding? I have the same problem when I import css from outside. I even used bootstrap css. Funny thing is that css's worked for some time and unexpectedly stopped.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are misspelling `background-color`. You have _backgraund-color_.

Comment: ok, thats fixed problem.